# Cannot assign fetched data to useState on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am having this issue. I am fetching data using axios and want to assign it to useState. However, all methods including the async function inside useEffect failed to do so. so the first console.log(res.data) shows all info nicely. However, the second one console.log(weather) displays an empty array.  Any suggestions?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


  // Side effects
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://weather-app-tst.herokuapp.com/api/weather")
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(res.data);
        
        setWeather(res.data);
        console.log(weather);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`weather` hasn't updated by the time that `console.log` happens.  `weather` should show the new value after the component rerenders